# How to refresh animation state in unity to know what animation is playing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so, I did this:

```
print(Anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).shortNameHash);
```

When I play an animation like so

```
Anim.Play("AnimationName");
```

The value printed changes and then stays the same and doesn't change back to the default animation.
I also tried with the following:

```
if (Anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("FireAnimation"))
```

I want to be able to get a constant update on the current animation that is playing. If you have any method that doesn't involve using a clock please do help.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the best way to do this is to use the animation controller and change varialbes using SetBool(); and SetFloat(); etc.